# Airy's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

$I(y)= \int_ \gamma \mathbb{e^{zy-\frac{z^3}{3}}}dz$. This integral is taken along the contour composed of $\mathbb{R_{+}}$ and $ \mathbb{e^\frac{2\pi}{3}}$*$\mathbb{R_{+}}$. Prove that this integral satisfies the Airy's equation:
$I''-yI=0$. 
Any hint?

Comment: Take the derivative? At some point you will have to integrate by parts...

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hint: (hope you can finish the job)

$$I''(y) = \int_\gamma \underbrace{z^2}_{=-\frac{d}{dz}(z y -z^3/3)+y} e^{z y -z^3/3}\,dz=- \int_\gamma e^{z y -z^3/3}\frac{d}{dz}(z y -z^3/3)\,dz +y I(y)\,.$$